# Should I be using multiple PostgreSQL queries for this?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a couple of tables.

**Table 1 (player_main)**

This table has a "id" column which is a UUID type and is the primary key.

**Table 2 (game_main)**

This table also has an "id" column of the UUID type and is a primary key.

**Table 3 (game_members)**
This table has a column "member_id" of UUID type which is a primary key and a foreign reference to player_main(id).
There is also an "game_id" column of UUID type which references game_main(id).

My problem is, if a player connects to the server, I want to be able to load up their "game data" by querying the database and receiving all the data to construct their data object. I am given the UUID of the player which is stored in player_main(id). I need to obtain the game_main(id) and a list of all the game member ids that correspond to that game_main(id).

How would I do this? I've attempted to do different types of joins with a where clause to identify the game_members(member_id) but that only returns the row that is correspondent to the member that has just joined, not a column containing all of the members for that game.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**Edit**

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT t1.member_id, t2.*
FROM game_members t1
INNER JOIN game_main t2
ON t1.game_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.member_id = <some UID>
```

which resulted in 1 row and 2 columns. The columns being "game_members.member_id" and "game_main.id". The value for the first column is the UUID that I specified in the where clause and the value for the second column is the UUID of the game. I was expecting to see 2 rows of data with the same "game_main.id" but with different "game_member.member_id"'s, as I have 2 entries in the same game currently.

**Edit 2**

As requested, I will provide sample data for my tables as well as the output that I wish to see.

Sample Data:

[player_main]

```
id                                  
------------------------------------|
863fdf91-86fb-49a7-9232-bcb596e3a86f|
7af64cd7-72a2-410f-9b5c-620127fca0ac|
c7b1952a-b263-470f-9cae-9d5e6d7a8186|
```

[game_main]

```
id
------------------------------------|
dd76c680-5853-40a6-b757-0457d1a7e95f|
ca4f5b1f-0f8c-4f10-969c-464ccf207d9c|
```

[game_members]

```
member_id                           | game_id       
------------------------------------|------------------------------------
863fdf91-86fb-49a7-9232-bcb596e3a86f|dd76c680-5853-40a6-b757-0457d1a7e95f
7af64cd7-72a2-410f-9b5c-620127fca0ac|dd76c680-5853-40a6-b757-0457d1a7e95f
c7b1952a-b263-470f-9cae-9d5e6d7a8186|ca4f5b1f-0f8c-4f10-969c-464ccf207d9c
```

[desired output]

This is what the game info of the player's current game should look like. The query should take only the player's UUID and return the following if I the UUID was equal to 863fdf91-86fb-49a7-9232-bcb596e3a86f

```
member_id                           | game_id       
------------------------------------|------------------------------------
863fdf91-86fb-49a7-9232-bcb596e3a86f|dd76c680-5853-40a6-b757-0457d1a7e95f
7af64cd7-72a2-410f-9b5c-620127fca0ac|dd76c680-5853-40a6-b757-0457d1a7e95f
```

Comment: If you want all records, then drop the `WHERE` clause, which is restricting the result set to a single user.

Comment: But that would retrieve rows for every single game, not just the game that the player belongs to.

Comment: Show sample data for all tables, along with your desired output.  This will make it completely clear what you want here.

Comment: I've included sample data and output.

Comment: Are you trying to find all users who have any games in common?

Comment: I am trying to find the game data of the game the user is in. Game data involves a list of users who are apart of that game.

Comment: Have a look at the query I gave below as I think this is closer to what you want than what I had before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a self-join of the `game_members` table.  The following query will generate all unique members who have any game in common with games used by a certain player.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.member_id, t1.game_id
FROM game_members t1
INNER JOIN game_members t2
    ON t1.game_id = t2.game_id
WHERE t1.member_id = <some UID>
```

Comment: I assume t1 is game_members, t2 is game_main, right?

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are just _aliases_ for the `game_members` and `game_main` tables.

Comment: Alright, then replacing all occurrences of t1 with game_members and t2 with game_main and the UUID in the where clause to one of the 2 UUIDs which are members of the same game id resulted in the following:
column "member_id" with the value being the uuid I specified in the where clause and column "id" with the value being the uuid of the game they are in.

Comment: @Reminant I'm not sure if you're really using Postgres here, but you don't need to remove the aliases, rather they make the query easier to read.  You should seriously update your question rather than starting a never ending exchange of comments.

Comment: Apologies, I'm quite new to Stack Overflow and PostgreSQL as well. I did not realise that the aliases were valid syntax, I thought they were for me to fill in. I have made an edit to the post, thank you for all the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could break down your problem into:

- looking up the player's current game in `game_members` and then,
- looking up the game's current players from the same `game_members` table

This approach translates to the following query involving a self-join:

```
select
    gm2.member_id,
    gm1.game_id
from 
    game_members gm1
        inner join game_members gm2 on
            gm1.game_id = gm2.game_id   -- lookup the game's current players
where
    gm1.member_id = '863fdf91-86fb-49a7-9232-bcb596e3a86f'  -- lookup the player's current game
```